# Creating a user with a password with Bash

Tags: bash, users, password

```
username=$1
pass=$2
shift
shift
fname=$*
username=$(useradd -m -s /bin/bash -c "$fname" $username)
newpass=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt -stdin $pass)
```

So this works, it's just when i try to log in, i can't. For the life of me I don't understand what is wrong. I tried it with the syntax:

```
newPass=($username:$pass | chpasswd -c SHA512)
```

Comment: Your use of `-salt -stdin` is misleading, potentially insecure, and probably not what you intended.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the assignment to `$newpass` (or `$newPass`)? Neither really makes any sense as written.

Comment: don't really care. The whole thing is insecure haha. Just need it to work :)

Comment: not using those variables for anything at the moment, but maybe down the line I will need them. It doesn't hurt to have them in.

Comment: It does hurt. They're meaningless

Comment: meaningless now, but doesn't hurt.

Comment: No. Meaningless period.

Comment: okay cool dude :) I don't really care. Do you have something to contribute or not?

Comment: There is zero advantage to putting any of this in a script.  Just use the `useradd` and `chpasswd` commands directly.  The whole script is meaningless and entirely pointless.  Downvoted for that, and for not caring at all about the quality of your code (as admitted in a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really must do this, here's a script that will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
username="$1"
pass="$2"
shift 2
fname="$*"

useradd -m -s /bin/bash -c "$fname" "$username"
echo "$username:$pass" | chpasswd
```

Here, the plaintext password in `$pass` gets encrypted into `/etc/shadow` by the `chpasswd` command. By default it uses PAM to perform the encryption, so it will be the "most suitable" for the target system.

Comment: is it encrypted? can you add a `chpasswd -e` to encrypt it?

Comment: this works :) thank you :) I appreciate your help